# Display a nicely formatted path in PowerShell have code how to format for profile

Tags: powershell

I found a snippet of code that if I paste in PowerShell It displays all of my windows path variables on one line. What would the syntax be for adding this code to my profile?

```
Push-Location env:
(ls path).value.split(";")
Pop-Location
```

Comment: You want to add this to your powershell profile?  You can just pipe the output of your split command to `Out-File $profile`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want add a function to your profile so that you can call this more easily?

Comment: @Raziel I think they're looking to make environmental variables persistent across PS sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this function in your PowerShell profile:

```
function Get-Path {
  $env:Path.Split(";")
}
```

After this function is defined, you can type `Get-Path` to see the list of directories in your `Path`.

If you don't already have a profile script, run the command `help about_Profiles` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd prefer to see PATH variable on one line, but here's the code to do it.

```
C:>(ls Env:\Path).value
```

I prefer separate lines:

```
C:>(ls Env:\Path).value.split(';')
```

As far as your PowerShell Profile goes, open PowerShell and run:

```
C:>$profile
```

It will tell you the path to your profile (make the file and directory if it doesn't exist).

Then, copy + paste the code above into it.

It will run whenever you open powershell.